# I am getting 131 kb instead of 507 kb

Tags: r

I want to just convert from float32 to 16b with scale factor of 10. I am supposed to get files with size of 507kb(720*360*2) not 131kb. Any help?

```
dir1 <- list.files("C:\\New folder (13)", "*.img", full.names = TRUE)
results <- list()
for (.files in seq_along(dir1)){
   file2 <- readBin(dir1[.files], double(), size = 4, n = 360*720, signed = TRUE)
   results[[length(results) + 1L]] <- file2[file2 != -9999]*10
   fileName <- sprintf("C:\\SWdown_200001_%d.bin", .files)
   writeBin(as.integer(results[[.files]]), fileName, size = 2)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each element in 'file2' which equals -9999 will not be present in results[[.files]].  Looks like approximately 3/4 of the elements in 'file2' equal this value.  Perhaps you want to assign a different value to these elements, rather than dropping them when assigning to results[[...]].

To do what you want, try this:

```
file2[file2 != -9999] <- file2[file2 != -9999]*10
results[[length(results) + 1L]] <- file2;
```

Comment: in fact i wanted to exclude them from multiplying by 10. how i solve this

Comment: or `results[[length(results) + 1L]] <- ifelse(file2!=-9999,file2*10,-9999)`